# UINavigationController is showing black screen after clicking on custom TableView cell

Tags: ios

Showing black screen after I click on a tableView cell. I am able to retrieve the text on that cell but with the black screen. Please help.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   //Get cell text
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *myCell;
    myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BasicCell"];
    myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"BasicCell"];
    NSString *val = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];


    //Load Image view
    UINavigationController *NavViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImageView"];
    [self presentViewController:NavViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are getting a selected cell  then creating a new cell  and after that presenting a navigation controller? What you want to achieve from this?

Comment: You are trying to load an Image on the click of the cell?

Comment: I am trying to load navigation controller after selecting a cell and based on that selected cell I want to load a URL image in that navigation controller.

Comment: U mean you want to navigate a whole new view on the click of the cell..

Comment: Wait let me try a solution for you, will get back to you in a while.

Comment: Can you give me a sample image Url to check with?

Comment: sample url: http://www.fpjuris.com.br/fotos/apple-iphone-3gs-01.jpg

Comment: have you read any documentation or tried to learn through tutorials or anything? Your code is far from getting you to your destination. You should look up some tutorials. Ray Wenderlich is pretty good or App Coda.

Comment: Hey I have done it, I can paste the code and then mail it to you...

Comment: U there? I ve achieved the funtionality... I need to rush home then tell me fast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever You get time, just look at this:

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
strUrl=[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ImageView" sender:nil];
```

I am passing the Image url to the next view controller as above.

And then, pass the `strUrl` to the next `viewController` like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ImageView"]){

        LoadedImageViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.strSelectedImageUrl=strUrl;
    }
}
```

And lastly, in the `LoadedImageViewController`: add this code in `- (void)viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Loading Image..."];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fpjuris.com.br/fotos/apple-iphone-3gs-01.jpg"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        if ( img == nil )
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.imgLoadedImage.image = img;
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        });
    });

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And you are done!!!
All the best....

Comment: This code is working as expected. Thanks much Kanan !